# Connect Oracle SQL developer to Microsoft SQL server 2017

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbvisualizer

I recently installed Microsoft SQL server 2017 on my computer and I also installed Microsoft SQL Management Studio and everything seems to work pretty well.

One of my colleague told me that I could use a third party Database manager, so I was trying to connect my Oracle SQL developer with it.
The thing is that I needed a driver (for SQL server) I downloaded, but when I tried to add it in SQL developer, it didn't recognize it.

Here is the Microsoft driver I used >> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=868290

But he could recognize it with this JTDS driver which doesn't seem to be the right one >> https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/

Anyway, neither of those drivers could allow me to connect.

I also tried to use DBVisualizer instead of Oracle SQL Developer, same issue...

Do you have any clue?

Thanking you in advance.

Screenshots:

Connection with SQL Developer:

[image: Connection with SQL Developer]

Connect with DBVisualizer

[image: Connect with DBVisualizer]

Data from SQL Server Configuration Manager

[image: Data from SQL Server Configuration Manager]

Comment: You'd be far better off using Microsoft's Sql Server Management Studio, for the same reason that a rock could be used as a hammer, but it's not as good of a hammer as a hammer is

Comment: I believe that there is no direct way to connect to the SQL server from Oracle's SQL Developer. I can imagine that you can try to connect via Oracle Gateway, but the SQL developer do not support MSSQL.

Comment: You shouldn't be using jTDS any more. Use the Microsoft JDBC driver.

Comment: The "port" property in SQL Developer can only contain a number, not a JDBC URL. For SQL Developer try to use the "Advanced" connection type, then enter the complete JDBC URL, e.g. `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/your_database_name`  But the error "connection refused" seems to indicate that your SQL Server isn't listening on port 1433 or TCP/IP connections have not been enabled.

Comment: We support SQL server connections, but only with the jtds driver, get version 1.3

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old thread but I am posting a working solution for any future visitor.

I am using SQL Developer Version [19.2.1.247] and connected to SQL Server Express 2017 on localhost.

Using jtds-1.3.1.jar downloaded from [sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/)

Follow these steps:

1.Download and unzip the file into the main SQL Developer directory (or the directory of your choice).

2.In SQL Developer go to Tools -> Preferences -> Database -> Third party JDBC Drivers. Click the “add entry” button

3.Navigate to the jtds-1.3.1.jar file.

4.Save and exit preferences.

5.Close and restart SQL Developer

Open “Add Connection” – there should now be a SQL Server tab.

Above steps are common and if you search on google you will get most of the sites having above mentioned steps.

THE PROBLEM WHICH I FOUND WAS THE DB PORT 1433 which is default port showing in connection dialoge need to be correct as your DB PORT.

I use below command to know my DB PORT.

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -d master -h -1 -W -Q "xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on'"
```

based on result I found the port is 55993, see below image

[image: image here]

By changing port to the current one I am able to connect successfully.

see below image

[image]

Hope it will help!